# Fazer slide Vertical com scroll e fade e parallax

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, slider

Queria fazer um slide igual ao deste site: http://www.midtownatlinnovates.com/why-midtown/ , onde a informação é dividida na vertical e ao fazer scroll para baixo vai alterando a imagem e a info.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Alguém me sabe dar uma luz para isso?

Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Da maneira que você quer eu não sei exatamento como fazer, mas posso te dar uma luz com o uso de um plugin chamado **Slick** slider.

URL: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Abraços!